# What percent of males in the sample own their own home?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, tables

[image]

I said it was (males who own a house) divided by total number of males: 
132 / (132 + 50) which equals to 72.5%

However, my professor seems to think it is the # of male who own the house divided by 348.
Answer keys I have looked at say it's 72.5%, can someone explain why?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a language issue to me. You have interpreted the problem correctly and the answer is 72.5%.

The question that his answer answers is "of those observations sampled, what percentage are male homeowners?".

This, however, is not the question, and so your professor is either having a language problem or is misinformed on the most basic of statistical concepts.